# My anti-swear code doesn't work, what's the reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am coding an anti-swear bot. But it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code -

```
@client.command()
async def addword(ctx,* ,word = None):
  if word == None:
    await ctx.send("You have one option :\n`a-addword <swear_word_here>`")

  openfile = open(f"{ctx.guild.id}.txt", "r+")
  contents = openfile.read()

  for x in contents:
    if x == "word":
      await ctx.send('That word is already censored!')
    else:
      openfile.write(f"{word}")
      await ctx.send("Added the word to server's censor list!")
```

This code is for adding words into the txt file. But it doesn't even add a word. I did find out that it doesn't respond to any commands either. Neither does it give any errors.

Here's the code where it checks if the message is the same as any word in the txt file,

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
  author = msg.author
  channel = msg.channel
  em = discord.Embed(title="Swear word warning", description = f"{author.mention} You're not allowed to say that <:angry_pepe:781377642410409994>.")

  contentofmsg = msg.content.lower()
  try:
    f = open(f"{msg.guild.id}.txt", "r")
    contents = f.read()
  except FileNotFoundError:
    f = open(f"{msg.guild.id}.txt", "a+")
    contents = []

  for x in contents:
    if x == contentofmsg:
      await msg.delete()
      await channel.send(author.mention, embed=em)
    else:
      return

  await client.process_commands(msg)
```

It still gives the same error, I have no idea why.
If you know the answer to this, please do answer me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error pretty much speaks for itself... The file is not found

Comment: you are trying to read a file before it exists on the first run

Comment: mhm no. I checked the it in the file explorer and it WAS THERE. So idk y it shows that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error says that the file to read is not found:**

> **FileNotFoundError**: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '800964569055887360'"

This issue happens because python does not create the file when you open it in read (`"r"`) mode.

You can avoid this error by:

**1. Manually creating the file**
or
**2. Use `try: ... except:` like that:**

```py
try: # the file exists
    openfile = open(f"{ctx.guild.id}.txt", "r")
    contents = openfile.read()

except FileNotFoundError: # the file does not exist
                          # create it and create "contents" (empty for the moment)
    open(f"{ctx.guild.id}.txt", "a+")
    contents = []
```

Comment: Why did you unaccept? Doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: I wasn't aware I unaccepted, it did solve *a bit* of my command, u gave answer to only half of my command... it's all good now tho.

Comment: OK - I can still search for a complete solution. Otherwise you can [**ask another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).